# Returning an instance of a node itself in a php tree class

Tags: php, tree

So I'm trying to create a tree structure in PHP. I don't know if that's possible and I'm not all that great with PHP so this is difficult for me.

The code I have so far is (important stuff only, extra code has been cut out):

```
abstract class tree_node {
    protected $_child_refs = array();

    abstract public function add_child($arg);

    public function count() {
        return count($this->_child_refs);
    }

    public function get_deepest_children() {
        if ($this->count() === 0) {
            return $this;
        } else {
            foreach ($this->_child_refs as $child_ref) {
                $deepest[] = $child_ref->get_deepest_children();
            }
        }
    }

    abstract public function __construct();
}

class data_node extends tree_node {
    private $_data = "";

    public function add_child($data) {
        $new_child = new data_node($data);
        $this->_child_refs[] = $new_child;
    }

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->_data = $data;
    }
}

$foo = new data_node("foo");
$foo->add_child("bar");

var_dump($foo->get_deepest_children());
```

This code should return a data_node with "bar" as the data but instead I get NULL. What's wrong with "return $this"? Is that not the proper way to return an instance of a class itself?

Also, feel free to critique this code/tell me I'm doing this completely wrong. I want to keep tree functions separate from functions specific to the data stored in the tree, which is why I split it up into two classes, but if you think that's a bad idea tell me.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to get back from the `get_deepest_children` method? Right now it just constructs a list of children of the current node, then does nothing with it.

Comment: It's supposed to "get the deepest children," that is, return an array of all the children that don't have any children. If I were to add a child "foobar" to "bar" $foo->get_deepest_children would return "foobar", not "bar".

Also, I need to be able to modify those children, and have the modifications affect them in the tree.

Comment: If you can have multiple deepest children (and you can), I think the return should be an array (or some other custom container) and a.t.m. the root node doesn't return anything if it isn't `count()===0`.

Comment: Okay, the conventional name for that is [leaf node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_node).

Comment: Oh, man. I knew I was missing something stupid. I gotta check my code more carefully before asking questions!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
public function get_deepest_children() {
    if ($this->count() === 0) {
        return $this;
    } else {
        foreach ($this->_child_refs as $child_ref) {
            $deepest[] = $child_ref->get_deepest_children();
        }
    }
}
```

Should be something like this:

```
public function get_deepest_children() {
    if ($this->count() === 0) {
        return array($this);
    }
    $deepest = array();
    foreach ($this->_child_refs as $child_ref) {
        $deepest = array_merge($deepest,$child_ref->get_deepest_children());
    }
    return $deepest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_deepest_children` isn't always returning the same type of value. In the base case it will return a node object, in the other cases it extends the `$deepest` list but doesn't return any value.

```
<?php
public function get_deepest_children() {
    if ($this->count() === 0) {
        return $this;
    } else {
        foreach ($this->_child_refs as $child_ref) {
            $deepest[] = $child_ref->get_deepest_children();
        }
    }
}
```

I would modify it like this:

```
<?php
public function get_deepest_children() {
    if ($this->count() === 0) {
        return Array($this);
    } else {
        $deepest = Array();

        foreach ($this->_child_refs as $child_ref) {
            $deepest = array_merge($deepest, $child_ref->get_deepest_children());
        }

        return $deepest;
    }
}
```

You should be able to see how it now always it returns an array of all of the deepest nodes (usually called [leaf nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaf_node)) below/including the current one. This way we can `array_merge` the consecutive results to get the final ones.

Comment: Hah, save for whitespace, else-construct and capitalization exactly the same. Shall we say great minds think alike?